# Restrict a user to add more than 5 attribute for player

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have tableA (fields: playerId, skill)

So my question is: how to make so that user can not add more than 5 same playerId?

Table's which method to override and what to do?

Tanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new integer field AttributeNum. You can override the insert() or the initValue() on the table depending on you requirement. Choose initValue() over insert() if you would like to keep your set-based operation fast on this table.

In the overriden method you can use query to aggregate and count the number of attributes per your current record.

Edit:

Alternately you can just override the `validateWrite()` method on the table.

```
boolean validateWrite()
{
    TableA        tableA;
    boolean       ret = super();    
    #define.MaxAttributes(5) // consider using setup         
    if (ret && !this.RecId)
    {
        select count(RecId) from tableA where tableA.PlayerId == this.PlayerId;    
        if (tableA.RecId >= #MaxAttributes)
        {    
            ret = checkFailed("Error message goes here");
        }    
    }
    return ret;
}
```

You didn't specify if the attributes should be unique per player or not but you should also consider creating the appropriate index in order to enforce data integrity.

You can find more information here:

[Maintain Fast SQL Operations [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa849875.aspx)

[Speeding Up SQL Operations [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa673589.aspx)

[Maintaining Data Integrity [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa672802.aspx)

[Data Model for New Microsoft Dynamics AX Modules [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa860987.aspx)

[Where to Place the Code [AX 2012]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa849024.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me a example of code? cause I'm new in SQL and AX : )

Comment: Code added. This is just an idea, only you can make it work in the context of your requirement :)

Also keep in mind, I didn't compile the code, so please take all this with a grain of salt.